# Arduino servo and IR remote

Tags: arduino, servo

I am trying to get a continuous (180 to 0 and back 0 to 180) movement from a servo when I press a button in remote and ONLY stop when I press the other button. So far, I have gotten it to move continuously, but then it doesn't stop when I press the 'stop' button. I know it is because of the while loop. However, I have tried switch-case, if statement, nothing has worked so far.
Please help, any advice for it make it work is appreciated.

```cpp
#include <Servo.h>

#define code1 2534850111 //decimal value of button 1
#define code3 16724175   //decimal value of button 1
#define code 4294967295   //random value
#define code2 16738455   //decimal value of button 0
#define code4 3238126971   //decimal value of button 0

Servo myservo; // servo object
int RECV_PIN = 11; //receiveing pin IR remote

int pos = 0;

IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN); 

decode_results results;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  irrecv.enableIRIn();  //start the receiver
  myservo.attach(9);    //servo connect to pin 9
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);   //LED connect to pin 2
}

void loop() {
  if(irrecv.decode(&results)){
     // if(results.value == code1 || results.value == code3){
     while(results.value == code1 || results.value == code3){
        digitalWrite(2,HIGH); //turn the led on
        for(pos = 0; pos <= 180; pos += 1){ //servo goes form 0 to 180             degrees in steps of 1 degree
    myservo.write(pos);
    delay(7);
    }
    for(pos = 180; pos >= 0; pos -= 1){ //servo goes back from 180 to 0 degrees with 1 degree step
    myservo.write(pos);
    delay(7);
}
    }

 while(results.value == code2 || results.value == code4){
       digitalWrite(2, LOW);  // turn the led off
       myservo.write(pos);
       delay(15);
       break;
 }

  Serial.println(results.value, DEC); //show the decimal value of the     pressed button
  irrecv.resume();  //receive the next value
    }

}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show us the code that you currently have. Without that (and often a wiring diagram), there's really no way we can help you.

Comment: My crystal ball doesn't tell me anything about your code... :(

Comment: Sorry, just learning this field. I thought there was a better way to attach the codes other than the 4 spaces in every line. However, thats not the problem, I hope you can help me now :)

Comment: If you actually look at the box you are writing into, you would notice a toolbar with helpful tools, like a button for putting 4 spaces in front of the code.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve your problem would be to check for the presence of a "button push" deeper inside `loop()`.  Put your checks for the button presses **inside** your movement `for` loop to catch the changes right away.  Looks like you might have two startcodes (?) so you might have to alter the `if` statements below, but hopefully I demonstrate how to check the condition to "keep going" in the code sample below.

```
void loop()
{
    if(irrecv.decode(&results))
    {
        // turn one way
        for(pos = 0; pos <= 180; pos += 1)
        {
            // only continue if the start code(s) still active
            if(results.value == STARTCODE || results.value == OTHERSTARTCODE)
            {
                myservo.write(pos);
                delay(7);
                irrecv.resume();  //receive the next value
            }
        }
        // turn the other way
        for(pos = 180; pos >= 0; pos -= 1)
        {
            // only continue if the start code(s) still active
            if(results.value == STARTCODE || results.value == OTHERSTARTCODE)
            {
                myservo.write(pos);
                delay(7);
                irrecv.resume();  //receive the next value
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your code looks better than mine, however doesn't exactly do what I wanted; the servo still does not continue to roll from 0 to 180 and back and keep on doing that until I press the "endcode". It does move everytime I press the button for 180 to 0 and also for 0 to 180(Ofc thats what the code is telling it do right). I am not sure if I have made the question clear, I hope it is though, please let me know if I can clear it up more somehow. Also, yes, I have two startcodes and also two endcodes.